# Static DNS records set in router seem to be ignored

Tags: windows, networking, dns, mikrotik-routeros

Router **MikroTik 951G-2HnD** works correctly as Wi-Fi router at address 192.168.1.1.
At Wi-Fi client, `ipconfig` shows this 192.168.1.1 also as DNS server for Wi-Fi adapter.

The router has configured two DNS servers.
Additionally, there are two [static DNS records](https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:IP/DNS#Static_DNS_Entries) set in the router:

```
> /ip dns static print  
 #    NAME      REGEXP    ADDRESS                          
 0    router              192.168.1.1                      
 1    tel                 192.168.1.4
```

Inside the router's console, both of the following commands work successfully:

```
ping router
ping tel
```

But they do not work in Windows PC connected to the router over the Wi-Fi.
They fail with `Unable to resolve target system name`*`router`*`.` (example for the first case).
Pinging corresponding IP addresses (e.g. 192.168.1.4) from the PC still works OK.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that there is not a cache problem on your client DNS? try some "/ipconfig /flushdns" and try again. And of course, PC has mikrotik router as first DNS server?

Comment: @BenoitPHILIPPON – The only DNS in Windows is that router. (There is one more DNS, but it is on HyperV adapter and related VM is switched off.) `ipconfig /flushdns` did not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### DNS Suffixes were in effect

I temporarily switched on `dns`+`debug` logging categories on the router and then command in PC

```
ping router
```

made a log record in router

```
question: router.aaa.example.com
```

Obviously, suffix `aaa.example.com` is being added. So I used `ipconfig /all` and found this:
(█ added for emphasis)

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : ABC123456
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : aaa.example.com █
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : aaa.example.com █
                                       bbb.example.com █
                                       ccc.example.com █

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : aaa.example.com █
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I219-LM
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : **-**-**-**-**-**
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

### Solution:

I changed static DNS mappings to

```
router.lan
tel.lan
```

and now `ping`**`router.lan`** (etc.) works successfully.